# How can i get rid of message box after user clicks cancel in dialog box in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net

I have a SaveAs dialog in my form to save an excel sheet. when i click the cancel in the dialog box, a another message box  appears asking "Do you want to save the changes made to  Book1?". i wish to get rid of this message box since the user has already decided not to save the excel  by clicking Cancel...please help.. thanks...

```
         Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim xlApp As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application
    Dim xlWorkBook As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook
    Dim xlWorkSheet As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet
    Dim misValue As Object = System.Reflection.Missing.Value

    Dim myArray(DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1, DataGridView1.Columns.Count - 1) As Object

    Dim r As Integer
    Dim c As Integer

    xlApp = New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ApplicationClass
    xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(misValue)
    xlWorkSheet = CType(xlWorkBook.Worksheets.Item("sheet1"), Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)
                                                                                                                 For r = 0 To DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1
        For c = 0 To DataGridView1.Columns.Count - 1
            myArray(r, c) = DataGridView1.Rows(r).Cells(c).Value
        Next cc 
       xlWorkSheet.Range("A1").Resize(DataGridView1.Rows.Count, DataGridView1.Columns.Count).Value = myArray
      Dim saveFileDialog As New SaveFileDialog()
    saveFileDialog.Filter = "Excel files (*.xlsx)|*.xlsx|All files (*.*)|*.*"
    saveFileDialog.FilterIndex = 2
    saveFileDialog.RestoreDirectory = True

    If saveFileDialog.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
        xlWorkSheet.SaveAs(saveFileDialog.FileName)
        MsgBox(" Your file has been saved")

    End If


    xlWorkBook.Close()
    xlApp.Quit()
    xlApp = Nothing
    xlWorkBook = Nothing
    xlWorkSheet = Nothing                                                                                            
 End Sub
```

Comment: Be careful, 'Cancel' actions should generally be non-destructive, I wouldn't expect an application to close and unsaved workbook upon clicking cancel, cancel should always be a safe option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this before quitting:

```
xlApp.DisplayAlerts = False
```

Or pass the `False` value to the close method:

```
xlWorkBook.Close(False)
```

Answer (score 1):

Call the close method with false to show no dialog.

```
xlWorkBook.Close(False)
```

[More on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.workbook.close%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)